# Step down in a Column and find a match - vba

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to use a for each and go trough a column (.range(A1:A500)) in Excel to find my specific value.

For example
Start in A1 and go down through the cells, if i find something called X then stop and insert a row above. After this i want to exit my for each.

Ive searched but i cant find a solution that will work for me. =/

Im grateful for any help in this case.

Comment: I find `Find` handy: `range(A1:A500).find("something")`, when I want to Find something.

Comment: `Find` is the best option for finding stuff.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through each cell in your range and find a match like this:

```
 Dim r as range
 For each r in range("a1:a500")
     If r = X then
        'found it
         if r.row>1 then
         rows(r.row-1).insert
         else
          rows(1).insert
         end if
         exit for
     end if
 Next r
```